# IN query into another IN query how to write in different way?

Tags: mysql

**i want this type of query with proper way how to write?**

```
SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE (
    id IN (SELECT user_id FROM tb_user_experience 
    WHERE
    company_name IN(SELECT company_name 
    FROM tb_company 
    WHERE tb_company.no_employee = '2'))
```

i know this is wrong query but how to get result with this logic in proper syntax of mysql?

this is half query my full query is below

```
SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE 
    steps_completed = 6 AND is_active='y' AND id != '1' AND 
    (country != '') AND (
    id IN (SELECT user_id FROM tb_user_experience WHERE 
    company_name IN(SELECT company_name FROM tb_company WHERE
    tb_company.no_employee = '2')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE 
    steps_completed = 6 AND is_active='y' AND id != '1' AND 
    (country != '') AND (
    id IN (  select e.user_id from tb_user_experience e 
     inner join tb_company c on c.company_name=e.company_name
     where c.no_employee = '2'))
```

Use Join Clause for better performance

Answer (score 0):

The query can also be re-written as:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM tb_user u
INNER JOIN tb_user_experience e 
    ON  u.id = e.user_id
    AND u.steps_completed = 6 
    AND u.is_active = 'y' 
    AND u.id != '1'
    AND u.country != ''
INNER JOIN tb_company c
    ON  c.company_name = e.company_name
    AND c.no_employee = '2'
```